# Email client for Linux Mint

Tags: linux, email-client

I am looking for an email client for Linux Mint. I am coming from Outlook and I need these settings:

- Start with system (I can start it with Mint Startup Manager, not important)
- New email notification alert (I installed new email notification on Thunderbird, but it’s not very good)
- New emails notification on system tray or somewhere I can see

Comment: I'll be migrating this over - but you probably should include a version, what DE if its not the standard one for mint, and what a "good new email notification alert" means to you

Comment: If you want something comparable to Outlook (and easily migrated), there isn't much that competes with Thunderbird.  It does what you've described.  If you don't like how something is implemented, there are endless add-ons to customize it.

Comment: As Journeyman already pointed out, the DE used may be a criterion here. As for "comparable to Outlook", there's Evolution shipping in the repositories. Thunderbird comes close as well with the right addons, and on KDE the KMail suite might be worth a look. But your specs are a bit flat to give good recommendations: what features do you need, apart from notifications? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: have you considered using outlook on linux?

Comment: Thunderbird pops up a notification when mail arrives if it is open (on my Mint 19 systems).

Answer (score 1):

I think that **Geary** fits the bill

https://mintguide.org/internet/349-geary-email-client-with-easy-interface-on-linux-mint.html

> - Desktop notification of new mail

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to try [`evolution`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_(software)) with some of it's plugins (`evolution-plugins`), but especially with `mail-notification-evolution` or `evolution-indicator` (depending on your desktop environment) installed, because it is IMHO the most "outlook-ish" native linux-application.

because you mentioned Thunderbird and perhaps satisfied with it or an other application, additionally installing (and setting up) `mail-notification` is enough. it is a separate program (therefore the clearly bigger client don't have to run all the time) and it works with any client you want to use - or even without one resp. webmail/browser.